# crontab versus manual running script

Tags: shell, cron

I wrote a script to check for wifi connection that has an "if then else" statement. If I run the script manually the "if" statement is 1, as it should, if the crontab runs it automatically the "if" is 0 and the script runs the else commands. Can someone imagine a reason for it to yield different results?

The script "if" condition is:

```
if ifconfig wlan0 | grep -q "inet addr:" ; then
```

Comment: Welcome to the RaspberryPi StackExchange.  Since this has nothing to do with the RaspberryPi specifically, this question isn't on topic here.  I would suggest trying Unix&Linux or StackOverflow.

Comment: A job running from cron will not have the same environment as your shell login session. Are you sure the commands are executing properly when run non-interactively?

Comment: Try debugging with `ifconfig wlan0 > /tmp/humtest1.out 2>&1` called by crontab and commandline.

Comment: What are you expecting to happen? 'grep -q' returns 0 as the exit status of lines are found, 1 if not found. Are you expecting the clause between then...fi to run or not run when 'inet addr:' is found?

Also, have you set something simple like "ifconfig wlan0 > /tmp/wlan0.txt" in you crontab to see what it does, exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ifconfig` binary resides in `/sbin`, which by default is not on the cron path. Use full paths to the commands:

```
if /sbin/ifconfig wlan0 | /bin/grep -q "inet addr:" ; then
```